# Binding in UWP (c#)

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

I have listview with binding:

```
 <ListView   x:Name="OrdersListView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" 
                    ItemClick="OrdersListView_ItemClick"  SelectedItem="{Binding AllRoundsSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I need to click element and receive data.

I do it like this.

```
    public RootObject allRoundsSelectedItem;
    public RootObject AllRoundsSelectedItem
    {
        get { return allRoundsSelectedItem; }
        set { allRoundsSelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private void OrdersListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

When i set breakpoint on this row `set { allRoundsSelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged();}`

I see that I have value that I need to have.

I try to enter data in another ListView.

Here code for it:

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="667" Margin="415,54,-124,-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989">
        <ListView   x:Name="DetailsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoundsSelectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="667" Width="989">
            <Grid x:Name="DetailGrid"  Height="667" Width="989"  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Время и дата заказа" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="214" FontSize="23"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding date_created}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Статус" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding status }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Осталось времени" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="На когда" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.city}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Сумма" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding total}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Имя" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Телефон" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.phone}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,308,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Адрес" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Количество персон" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.postcode}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Откуда" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,440,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Состав заказа" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,484,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Приметка для кухни" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,528,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Приметка для курьера" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel></DataTemplate></ListView.ItemTemplate></ListView>
```

But anything shows.

Where is my trouble?

Thank's for help so much!

Comment: I think, I don't understand your question completly, but to get data from View with click on it, you can use Command.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't very clear, so I can only guess as to what you were trying to achieve. It looks as though you want some kind of [master-detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface) interface, wherein you choose an item from the list (master) and then another form displays with controls for editing the data for that item (detail).

Your first ListView looks fine (and the binding works as you said). But why are you using another ListView for displaying the details of the selected item? ListViews are for displaying lists of data, but it appears that RootObject is not an array or collection class (I could be wrong, I don't know the class definition). You probably shouldn't be using a ListView, but whatever you use, you should bind the `AllRoundsSelectedItem` to the `DataSource` property of the panel.

Comment: Maybe you talk about ItemsSource?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** I mostly agree with @Decade Moon, but for the last line, there is no `DataSource` property of the `StackPanel` you used, I think this maybe is a typo, it should be `DataContext`. Anyway, here I'm writing this answer to give a demo for this solution:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="OrdersListView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single"
                ItemClick="OrdersListView_ItemClick"  SelectedItem="{Binding AllRoundsSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="Detail" Grid.Column="1" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Red" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Paramether1}" Margin="0,15" FontSize="20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Paramether2}" FontSize="20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Paramether3}" Margin="0,15" FontSize="20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Paramether4}" FontSize="20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Paramether5}" Margin="0,15" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If your layout is like this, then you can keep your most of the code in behind and in the `OrdersListView_ItemClick` event code like this:

```
private void OrdersListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    AllRoundsSelectedItem = e.ClickedItem as RootObject;
    Detail.DataContext = AllRoundsSelectedItem;
}
```

**Solution 2:** if you still want to use a `ListView` to show the details so can they be selected or something else, you can for example code like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="OrdersListView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single"
                ItemClick="OrdersListView_ItemClick"  SelectedItem="{Binding AllRoundsSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="DetailsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoundsSelectedItem}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="20" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And the type of `AllRoundsSelectedItem` should be `List` or `OberservableCollection`, it means you need to modify your code behind for example like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage ()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<RootObject> collection = new ObservableCollection<RootObject>();

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            collection.Add(new RootObject
            {
                ItemName = "Item " + i,
                Paramether1 = "Paramether1 " + i,
                Paramether2 = "Paramether2 " + i,
                Paramether3 = "Paramether3 " + i,
                Paramether4 = "Paramether4 " + i,
                Paramether5 = "Paramether5 " + i,
            });
        }
        OrdersListView.ItemsSource = collection;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> allRoundsSelectedItem;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> AllRoundsSelectedItem
    {
        get { return allRoundsSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            allRoundsSelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void OrdersListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.ClickedItem as RootObject;
        AllRoundsSelectedItem = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            item.ItemName,item.Paramether1,
            item.Paramether2, item.Paramether3,
            item.Paramether4, item.Paramether5,
        };
    }
}
```

By my side the `RootObject` class is like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Paramether1 { get; set; }
    public string Paramether2 { get; set; }
    public string Paramether3 { get; set; }
    public string Paramether4 { get; set; }
    public string Paramether5 { get; set; }
}
```

There are maybe other solutions, but you will need either modify your xaml code or the data type of your `AllRoundsSelectedItem`.